# How do I detect fail to connect wifi in android?

Tags: android, wifi

What is the best way to detect connection failure?

I know that we should use `NetworkInfo.getState()` to get connection state,
and also I use BroadcastReceiver with `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` to detecting connection state changes.

I think that detecting `DISCONNECTED` state in a broadcastReceiver is not match in this case.

`NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED` means only "disconnected", does not means connection fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register the Receiver with `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` to be notified when a connection failure occurs. It might be due to supplying invalid credentials for connecting to Wi-Fi.

```
private void registerReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
```

And your Receiver below

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (info != null) {
                if (info.isConnected()) {
                    //connected
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
                }
            }  else {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                    if (intent.hasExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR)) {
                      //failed to connect
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you and I am sorry for the late reply.

Comment: 'EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR' is deprecated as of API 28: Android 9.0 (Pie). The same goes for WifiManager.ERROR_AUTHENTICATING. What should we use now, what is the replacement? Any ideas? I tried using WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to detect wifi is connected or not

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) 
        // Connection Successful 
    else
        // Connection  Failed 
  }   
};
```